# PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: NameError: name 'wheel' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression, statsmodels

Trying to use the formula module in statsmodels to make linear regression model.

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd


cars = pd.concat([y_train, X_train], axis = 1)
cars.head()
model = smf.ols(formula ='price ~ symboling + wheel-base + length + width + height + curb-weight + engine-size + bore + stroke + compression-ratio + horsepower + peak-rpm + city-mpg + highway-mpg + cylinder',data=cars)
results = model.fit()
print(results.summary())
```

Comment: please provide the full error message

Comment: I did figure out the error. Thanks. The columns had hyphen in the name which were creating problems, i replaced them with underscore and viola. It worked. @PanagiotisSimakis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the errors by renaming my column header using underscore instead of the hyphen that it had. Hyphen must have triggered some expression in the code which i don't know anything about.